# Request from Controller/Index with Angular 2 doesnt work(ASP .Net MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angular

I try to use `Angular 2` with `MVC 4 .Net Framework`!(NOT .NET CORE MVC 6). I want still to use Views and I want to navigate from `localhost:XXX/Controller/Index` (.cshtml) in Browser but it doesn't work. I got Error `403 (Forbidden) localhost:XXX/app.`

If I try to navigate from `localhost:XXX` it works and it can access ../app. Where is the Problem?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access localhost:XXX/app successfully, you have to have an `AppController.cs` and a View

```
     public class AppController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
```